# Difference between encodeURLParameter, encodeURLPath and encodeURLQueryComponent?

Tags: kotlin, http, url, escaping, ktor

In Ktor there are those three `String` extension functions.

Semantically it is almost clear what they do (not completely clear).

In practical terms, I'm not sure what they do.

If I want to encode a part of a url path (`like/<<this>>/here`) what should I use?

If I want to encode a string that may contain `/` chars that I dont want escaped (ie `hello/beautiful/world`)?

If I want to encode a string that contains both `/` and spaces or http special chars like: `this/is seriously/weird`?

If I want to encode a string that goes into a query param?

If I want to encode a string that is both the key and the value of a query param?

Comment: FTR, this is not Kotlin per se, but rather extensions provided by Ktor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I want to encode a part of a url path (like/<<this>>/here) what should I use?

```
"<<this>>".encodeURLPathPart()
```

> If I want to encode a string that may contain / chars that I dont want escaped (ie hello/beautiful/world)?

```
"hello/beautiful/world".encodeURLPath()
```

> If I want to encode a string that contains both / and spaces or http special chars like: this/is seriously/weird?

```
// It depends on how do you want to encode it
"this/is seriously/weird".encodeURLParameter(spaceToPlus = true)
"this/is seriously/weird".encodeURLParameter()
"this/is seriously/weird".encodeURLPathPart()
```

> If I want to encode a string that goes into a query param?

> If I want to encode a string that is both the key and the value of a query param?

```
"param key/value".encodeURLQueryComponent(encodeFull = true)
```